# How to search for content file only in google drive api

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am using google drive api (v3).
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters

I need to search for some value in the content files in my google drive.
I am using the fullText field to search the value. My issue is the "fullText" give me a lot of irrelevant results because the value exists in metadata as well.

For example, I am looking for "john@gmail.com" (fullText contains 'john@gmail.com'), and let's assume I am John.

I want to see all the files that contain john@gmail.com in the content, but I am getting a lot of wrong results. The reason is I am the owner of the files and it exists in the metadata.

is there an option to search by content only?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What values do you want to exclude? Do you want to exclude results where the owner is `john@gmail.com`?

Comment: I want to search all the files that contain the value john@gmail.com, but I don't want to get a "noise" from files that has the john@gmail.com in their metadata (for example: owner, readers, shareWith and so on).

Comment: I'm not sure you can explicitly filter this "noise" when using the `fullText` field. You could use the `and` syntax to exclude using `not in` for `owners`, `readers`, `shareWith` etc.

Comment: This is I also saw and know, but I was excepted there is any trick for that. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[search](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters)

> Full text of the file including name, description, content, **and** indexable text.

This means that with the the `name, description, content, or indexable` text that contain your search string will be included in the results.

It will be up to you to clean up the files you dont want locally once the search has returned.

There is no way to only search content via the search method or to remove it from some and leave others its an all or nothing thing.

Comment: Nope no trick unless you want to send a feature request that they probably wont do :)